# OpenSpades "Failed to ddload 'libopenal.so'

Tags: 14.04

I've OpenSpades installed, as well as all dependencies, including libopenal...
When I run OpenSpades, it crashes with the following error:

> Failed to dlload 'libopenal.so':/usr/local/games//libopenal.so:
>   cannot read file daya: is a directory

Anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error go to your package manager and install *libopenal-dev* OpenSpades should now work.